# Error al subir proyecto de laravel en hosting CPANEL

Tags: cpanel

hola tengo un problema al subir mi proyecto de laravel en el hosting llamado CPANEL.
Subi todos mis archivos y ya modifique tambien el archivo index para que se comunique mi carpeta laravel con los archivos de public pero cuando quiero ingresar a mi proyecto desde el navegador me sale el siguiente error

1/1
RuntimeException in compiled.php line 7084:
No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

o estoy realizando mal mi subida de archivos a cpanel, si me pueden explicar cual fue mi error, grasias.

Comment: Lograste hacer funcionar tu proyecto en tu servidor alguna vez?, te pregunto esto porque basta con subir todo tu proyecto a tu servidor y en realidad no necesitas realizar ningun cambio, pero para llamar a tu pagina o sistema web debes hacerlo de la siguiente forma miservidor.com/proyecto/public/

Comment: si ya lo subi anteriormente y si funcionaba y para llamar a mi pagina me cree un subdominio el dominio principal es imsur.com.bo y el subdominio que me cree es test.imsur.com.bo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso se solucionaría facilmente con:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Pero debido a que quizás no tengas acceso por consola lo que hice una vez fue crear un archivo php con:

```php
<?php
    exec("php artisan key:generate");
```

Ponerlo en la ruta del proyecto y ejecutarlo.

También puedes probar ejecutando el comando en tu local y volver a subir todo.